# My website got infected with this php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

my website got infected by plugin and create ads with a company that im not with, I downloaded anti malware and they dont catch nothing.

```html
var doc = document.getElementById('ad_iframe').contentWindow.document;doc.open('text/html', 'replace');doc.write('\x3c!doctype html\x3e\x3chtml\x3e\x3chead\x3e\x3cmeta name\x3d\x22viewport\x22 content\x3d\x22width\x3d360, initial-scale\x3d1.0, minimum-scale\x3d1.0, maximum-scale\x3d1.0, user-scalable\x3dno\x22\x3e\x3cscript\x3evar jscVersion \x3d \x27r20210322\x27;\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript\x3evar google_casm\x3d[];\x3c/script\x3e\x3c/head\x3e\x3cbody leftMargin\x3d\x220\x22 topMargin\x3d\x220\x22 marginwidth\x3d\x220\x22 marginheight\x3d\x220\x22\x3e\x3cscript\x3ewindow.dicnf \x3d {};\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript data-jc\x3d\x2242\x22 data-jc-version\x3d\x22r20210322\x22 data-jc-flags\x3d\x22[\x26quot;x%278446\x26#39;9efotmy\x26quot;]\x22\x3e(function(){/*  Copyright The Closure Library Authors. SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 */ \x27use strict\x27;(class{constructor(a,b){this.g\x3db\x3d\x3d\x3dc?a:\x22\x22}}).prototype.toString\x3dfunction(){return this.g.toString()};var c\x3d{};window.viewReq\x3d[];const d\x3da\x3d\x3e{const b\x3dnew Image;b.src\x3da.replace(\x22\x26amp;\x22,\x22\x26\x22);window.viewReq.push(b)},e\x3da\x3d\x3e{fetch(a,{keepalive:!0,credentials:\x22include\x22,redirect:\x22follow\x22,method:\x22get\x22,mode:\x22no-cors\x22}).catch(()\x3d\x3e{d(a)})};window.vu\x3da\x3d\x3e{window.fetch?e(a):d(a)};}).call(this);\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript\x3evu(\x22https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/adview?ai\\x3dCHtZJ5KNfYOi4E4ON-cAPoK2TuA7tnIrOXY75-6rkCMCNtwEQASAAYKWWpIa0KIIBF2NhLXB1Yi01MDA3MDQ0NDA0NzMxMzYxyAEJqAMBqgTlAU_QpyZpF37sEdtwscUdq9r-TEbxY3uKITLsuNBCoN_LFBLsq2v30iDRZLSBcp7748eP28ixsxxL5uKAG1qtcb_1-tSvH6T6Chalwt4QGQR49yib74f7h1AbOJXNZ2fuEgBpZBjn27sPD16iWRIYqcgBtmBwRH6hOKvW_diwN9w_izOvXetI3_YlUAJtwohnIzNKEk7ygH6RyH2Ezf7ga3bQlX1Zr_5lfi2FTc6HKng1sWooYp4xNH0Mwf5XSxivRJBg1ARlpEimRFtuISnj313kj6AlX9qAyRcIy6HgGlT9wv1G3saABqeIitq5j-2lZqAGIagHpr4bqAfw2RuoB_LZG6gH7NUbqAeW2BvYBwDSCAUIiGEQAYAKAfoLAggBgAwB0BUBgBcBshcYChYSFHB1Yi01MDA3MDQ0NDA0NzMxMzYx\\x26sigh\\x3dGSgJADapxCE\\x26tpd\\x3dAGWhJmsCN7WtepqXmLH9rHprRB5zI2BbGaPF418An7D3hoO3lA\x22)\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript\x3evu(\x22https://notify.mgid.com/google/nurl?e\\x3dYBr4B6qPIsDqKtDyP_f0b_86Fg6PT950I_z91Pb_VvLKa-V9ZRr5EvUOhcpMTg9Ya0Oznv3Cevtwffx1HWE8eX2ffPVpCRIjDhCCwpSnsK5tBGLRRZ3kPl3OCJStg68clEmDnNRnvlvZeBvw1KWkQCYfOR0yM9axobvqUZdtYspPjVeUkYQHgWDBkAewu-bDifDPErWm9sk0oF66Bq3Z_J69m0UPaAxX1Ebid_27mM8SociTLThy0HGcdCcx8p4M37v-aoOyqUWIDyg_CZt84UV8NfSTSSyTPM4tMGgpgR-Hlh_FRbvmi7MEIKcdhBAtRgnnf2RuQJcJxFIpr2Ox5-RquYI8SNeSTc6HJbcBZ7IGt6DMUkRdnUyoAqSZsjDILdlRJl9sSkYtr-vp3Zwikg\\x26rq\\x3d605fa3e4000580a2021e40276106d50a\\x26v\\x3d4\\x26s\\x3dYF-j5AAE3GgCHkaDAATWoJ8hHu5LOCozNRt-dA\x22)\x3c/script\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22GoogleActiveViewInnerContainer\x22style\x3d\x22left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:100%;position:fixed;pointer-events:none;z-index:-9999;\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv style\x3d\x22display:inline\x22class\x3d\x22GoogleActiveViewElement\x22data-google-av-cxn\x3d\x22https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pcs/activeview?xai\x3dAKAOjsvwcG_Zhy-lBYI1m2ybZsQCsG7_ZqyCUtRu86W8XYtrZDWS6G2nSFdWOEL12XjfwlZ_SZ4M369wd5dPGzH9uhrsIX8Rsm9zug\x26amp;sig\x3dCg0ArKJSzBc1b2utzj0JEAE\x22data-google-av-adk\x3d\x222196351605\x22data-google-av-metadata\x3d\x22la\x3d0\x26amp;xdi\x3d0\x26amp;\x22data-google-av-override\x3d\x22-1\x22data-google-av-dm\x3d\x222\x22data-google-av-immediate data-google-av-aid\x3d\x220\x22data-google-av-naid\x3d\x221\x22data-google-av-slift\x3d\x22\x22data-google-av-cpmav\x3d\x22\x22data-google-av-btr\x3d\x22\x22data-google-av-itpl\x3d\x2220\x22data-google-av-rs\x3d\x222\x22data-google-av-flags\x3d\x22[\x26quot;x%278440\x26#39;9efotm(\x26amp;753374%2bejvf/%27844\x26gt;\x26#39;9efotm(\x26amp;75337:%2bejvf/%278456\x26#39;9efotm(\x26amp;2006706?\x26amp;\x26gt;`dopb~\x26quot;]\x22\x3e\x3cscript\x3evar s1\x3d\x222688883422\x22,MarketGidC980301DisableStart \x3d true;\nvar _mgq\x3d_mgq||[];\n_mgq.push([\x22MarketGidLoadGoods980301\x22,[\n[\x22Bystock\x22,\x228676024\x22,\x221\x22,\x22Розпродаж конфіскату! Samsung Galaxy S20 за копійки!\x22,\x22\x22,\x220\x22,\x22\x22,\x22\x22,\x22\x22,\x22UNjcQrdwTqojknWma5MBMmgRXxKLj6LIHICGuTCtIi_bnEw2MVVaVlU_QKnzp0Sk\x22,{\x22i\x22:\x22https://s-img.mgid.com/g/8676024/370x209/-/aHR0cDovL2NsLmltZ2hvc3RzLmNvbS9pbWdoL2ltYWdlL2ZldGNoL2FyXzE2OjksY19maWxsLGVfc2hhcnBlbjoxMDAsZl9qcGcsZ19mYWNlczphdXRvLHdfMTAyMC9odHRwOi8vaW1naG9zdHMuY29tL3QvMjAyMS0wMy8yNzQ3ODQvZjJmM2Q3NmIwY2NlMDhlYmE5ZDI4NGJhN2JiZGRjYmEuanBn.jpg?v\x3d1616880612-Y2v8ox4vAR2lHovayAAOM5n1ODlA5u_6CJUBMyho54A\x22,\x22l\x22:\x22https://adclick.g.doubleclick.net/aclk?sa\x3dL\x26ai\x3dCkSLM5KNfYOi4E4ON-cAPoK2TuA7tnIrOXY75-6rkCMCNtwEQASAAYKWWpIa0KIIBF2NhLXB1Yi01MDA3MDQ0NDA0NzMxMzYxyAEJqAMBqgToAU_QpyZpF37sEdtwscUdq9r-TEbxY3uKITLsuNBCoN_LFBLsq2v30iDRZLSBcp7748eP28ixsxxL5uKAG1qtcb_1-tSvH6T6Chalwt4QGQR49yib74f7h1AbOJXNZ2fuEgBpZBjn27sPD16iWRIYqcgBtmBwRH6hOKvW_diwN9w_izOvXetI3_YlUAJtwohnIzNKEk7ygH6RyH2Ezf7ga3bQlX1Zr_5lfi2FTc6HKng1sWooYp4xNH0Mwf5XSxivRJBg1ARlpEimRFtuISnj313kj6BnXdcSAPPXjFk_ELoy3Reh9NPe-neABqeIitq5j-2lZqAGIagHpr4bqAfw2RuoB_LZG6gH7NUbqAeW2BvYBwDSCAUIiGEQAfoLAggBgAwB0BUBgBcB\x26num\x3d1\x26sig\x3dAOD64_1d6s6rh0FcrJ7UZQDiv-swY8_8PQ\x26client\x3dca-pub-5007044404731361\x26adurl\x3d%2F%2Fwww.mgid.com%2Fghits%2F8676024%2Fi%2F103535%2F0%2Fsrc%2F2688883422%2Fpp%2F1%2F1%3Fh%3DUNjcQrdwTqojknWma5MBMmgRXxKLj6LIHICGuTCtIi_bnEw2MVVaVlU_QKnzp0Sk%26rid%3D9cf382bc-8f43-11eb-ac08-001e6768a194%26pubsrcid%3D2688883422\x22,\x22adc\x22:[],\x22sdl\x22:1,\x22dl\x22:\x22https://bystock.me/45389b0193\x22,\x22type\x22:\x22w\x22,\x22clicktrackers\x22:[],\x22cta\x22:\x22Дізнатися більше\x22}\n]],{\x22awc\x22:{},\x22dt\x22:\x22mobile\x22,\x22ts\x22:\x22\x22,\x22tt\x22:\x22\x22,\x22isBot\x22:0,\x22h2\x22:\x22xsQ4hymwEk6IizbzBv-mXnkjxRdOHP8ozg7aLYCfHdc*\x22,\x22ats\x22:0,\x22rid\x22:\x229cf382bc-8f43-11eb-ac08-001e6768a194\x22,\x22psid\x22:\x222688883422\x22,\x22pvid\x22:\x22\x22,\x22iv\x22:0,\x22brid\x22:5,\x22muidn\x22:\x22\x22,\x22dnt\x22:2,\x22cv\x22:3}]);\n\n\x3c/script\x3e\x3cdiv id\x3d\x22M616816ScriptRootC980301\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cscript src\x3d\x22https://jsc.mgid.com/a/d/adx.google.com.ua.980301.js\x22 async\x3e\x3c/script\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cscript data-jc\x3d\x2222\x22 src\x3d\x22https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20210322/r20110914/client/window_focus_fy2019.js\x22 async data-jc-version\x3d\x22r20210322\x22 data-jcp-url\x3d\x22https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/interaction/?ai\x3dCkSLM5KNfYOi4E4ON-cAPoK2TuA7tnIrOXY75-6rkCMCNtwEQASAAYKWWpIa0KIIBF2NhLXB1Yi01MDA3MDQ0NDA0NzMxMzYxyAEJqAMBqgToAU_QpyZpF37sEdtwscUdq9r-TEbxY3uKITLsuNBCoN_LFBLsq2v30iDRZLSBcp7748eP28ixsxxL5uKAG1qtcb_1-tSvH6T6Chalwt4QGQR49yib74f7h1AbOJXNZ2fuEgBpZBjn27sPD16iWRIYqcgBtmBwRH6hOKvW_diwN9w_izOvXetI3_YlUAJtwohnIzNKEk7ygH6RyH2Ezf7ga3bQlX1Zr_5lfi2FTc6HKng1sWooYp4xNH0Mwf5XSxivRJBg1ARlpEimRFtuISnj313kj6BnXdcSAPPXjFk_ELoy3Reh9NPe-neABqeIitq5j-2lZqAGIagHpr4bqAfw2RuoB_LZG6gH7NUbqAeW2BvYBwDSCAUIiGEQAfoLAggBgAwB0BUBgBcB\x26amp;sigh\x3d8NNjLIQD-l8\x26amp;cid\x3dCAQSPwCNIrLM0homDPN7rMyuRZKq05FrXmncFosI_51fmWf7Uq-UJoPRBPfI59QVPeYR_768gsh4TuFHeMvAYtxjrw\x22 data-jcp-gws-id\x3d\x225KNfYKavEo2OZ_C3rOgE\x22 data-jcp-qem-id\x3d\x22COi6qtS10e8CFYNGHgIdoNYE5w\x22\x3e\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript src\x3d\x22https://www.googletagservices.com/activeview/js/current/rx_lidar.js?cache\x3dr20110914\x22\x3e\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript type\x3d\x22text/javascript\x22\x3eosdlfm(-1,\x27\x27,\x27BWOvx5KNfYOi4E4ON-cAPoK2TuA4Ajvn7quQIAAAQATgByAEJoAYh0ggFCIhhEAE\x27,\x27\x27,2196351605,true,\x27la\\x3d0\\x26xdi\\x3d0\\x26\x27,3,\x27\x27,\x27https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pcs/activeview?xai\\x3dAKAOjsvwcG_Zhy-lBYI1m2ybZsQCsG7_ZqyCUtRu86W8XYtrZDWS6G2nSFdWOEL12XjfwlZ_SZ4M369wd5dPGzH9uhrsIX8Rsm9zug\\x26sig\\x3dCg0ArKJSzBc1b2utzj0JEAE\x27,\x27\x27,\x27[\\x22x%278440\\x279efotm(\\x26753374%2bejvf/%27844\\x3e\\x279efotm(\\x2675337:%2bejvf/%278456\\x279efotm(\\x262006706?\\x26\\x3e`dopb~\\x22]\x27);\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript data-jc\x3d\x2223\x22 src\x3d\x22https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20210322/r20110914/client/qs_click_protection_fy2019.js\x22 data-jc-version\x3d\x22r20210322\x22\x3e\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript\x3egoogqscp.init([[[[null,1000,99,2,4,null,null,null,1],[null,500,99,2,9,null,null,null,1],[null,500,99,2,8,null,null,null,1]]],null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1]);\x3c/script\x3e\x3cscript\x3ewindow.parent.postMessage(\x27{\x22googMsgType\x22:\x22pvt\x22,\x22token\x22:\x22AGkb-H-PY8W7xw2JbRLOKISIQ_Ae8GOXwp6g9bPmXMhiiLk7KsoWxq1nzkQ1X90llhQqcgIbyMn6BWbWaqjnlg\x22}\x27, \x27*\x27);window.top.postMessage(\x27{\x22msg_type\x22:\x22adsense-labs\x22,\x22key_value\x22:[{\x22key\x22:\x22settings\x22,\x22value\x22:\x22[\\\\\\\x22ca-pub-5007044404731361\\\\\\\x22,[[1]]]\x22}],\x22googMsgType\x22:\x22sth\x22}\x27, \x27*\x27);window.top.postMessage(\x27{\x22key_value\x22:[{\x22key\x22:\x22qid\x22,\x22value\x22:\x22COi6qtS10e8CFYNGHgIdoNYE5w\x22}],\x22googMsgType\x22:\x22adpnt\x22}\x27, \x27*\x27);\x3c/script\x3e\x3cdiv style\x3d\x22display:none\x22 data-google-query-id\x3d\x22COi6qtS10e8CFYNGHgIdoNYE5w\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cdiv style\x3d\x22bottom:0;right:0;width:86px;height:250px;background:initial !important;position:absolute !important;max-width:100% !important;max-height:100% !important;pointer-events:none !important;image-rendering:pixelated !important;z-index:2147483647;background-image:url(\x27data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACsAAAAWBAMAAACrl3iAAAAABlBMVEUAAAD+AciWmZzWAAAAAnRSTlMAApidrBQAAAB6SURBVBjTbZABDoAwCAPLD/j/axVaWJcMzQzZpR4A7wrW//UOyL7tM3O74gL2dFc32VTyVbd0Jzr9zB6TSZbJVoVe3hBZoZ6dym0P/mAIscBOSZAkJ3Bc5ncpX+rH9FrlmTIlpeQxjTAl3yDc49pgjMtkm7hvkCsU+wFXKQWxF1fs+AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg\x3d\x3d\x27) !important;\x22\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cscript data-jc\x3d\x2228\x22 data-jc-version\x3d\x22r20210322\x22\x3e(function(){/*  Copyright The Closure Library Authors. SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 */ \x27use strict\x27;var e\x3dthis||self;function f(a,b,c){return a.call.apply(a.bind,arguments)}function…
```

Comment: How i can deleted please !

Comment: Delete the entire web site and restore from the last clean backup. Disable any suspect plugins and find better versions.

Comment: "_got infected by plugin_" Which plug-in? Is it a browser plug-in, or a server-side library? A browser plug-in can't access your server, you've to find a vulnerability from your server-side code. Also, make sure this is not added by your service provider, this might be a cost of a free server, or it could be a part of your contract with your service vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Standard anti malware is not going to help you out in this case. If you are using a cms your best bet is to do the following:

- restore the entire site from a clean backup.
- disable (all) plugins, or the suspected plugin casing the security hole.
- manually check and copy over newer content.

If you have no clean backup I would suggest carefully recreating the site from scratch and making sure to not copy over any injected scripts.

In order to mitigate this;

- follow a cms hardening guide. For example: https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/
- use a webhosting that offers services like patchman that can automatically scan for vulnerabilities